# Jquery Uncaught Error Syntax error, unrecognized expression: li/label

Tags: javascript, jquery, newsletter, uncaught-exception

I want to insert a cookie notification bar. Now on a old Newsletter page I get a error like this:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: li/label

the following code from the newsletter is

```
if( document.addEventListener ) document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', cmxform, false );

    function cmxform(){
      // Hide forms
      $( 'form.cmxform' ).hide().end();

      // Processing
      $( 'form.cmxform' ).find( 'li/label' ).not( '.nocmx' ).each( function( i ){
      var labelContent = this.innerHTML;
      var labelWidth = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle( this, '' ).getPropertyValue( 'width' );
      var labelSpan = document.createElement( 'span' );
        labelSpan.style.display = 'block';
        labelSpan.style.width = labelWidth;
        labelSpan.innerHTML = labelContent;
      this.style.display = '-moz-inline-box';
      this.innerHTML = null;
      this.appendChild( labelSpan );
      } ).end();

      // Show forms
      $( 'form.cmxform' ).show().end();
    }

    //function to check empty fields

    function isEmpty(strfield1, strfield2) {

    strfield1 = document.forms.newsletter_subscribe.nome.value 
    strfield2 = document.forms.newsletter_subscribe.email.value

      if (strfield1 == "" || strfield1 == null || !isNaN(strfield1) || strfield1.charAt(0) == ' ')
      {
      alert("Please insert your name!")
      return false;
      }

      if (strfield2 == "" || strfield2 == null || strfield2.charAt(0) == ' ')
      {
      alert("Please insert a valid Email!")
      return false;
      }

      return true;
    }

    //function to check valid email address
    function isValidEmail(){
      validRegExp = /^[^@]+@[^@]+.[a-z]{2,}$/i;
      strEmail = document.forms.newsletter_subscribe.email.value;

     // search email text for regular exp matches
      if (strEmail.search(validRegExp) == -1) 
     {
      alert('Email not valid! Please retry!');
      return false;
      } 
      return true; 
    }

    //function to check privacy
    function Privacy()
     {
     if (document.forms.newsletter_subscribe.checkbox.checked==false)
      {
      alert('Please accept the privacy conditions!');
      return false;
      }
      return true;
    }

    //function that performs all functions, defined in the onsubmit event handler

    function check(){
    if (isEmpty()){
            if (isValidEmail()){
                if (Privacy()) {
              return true;
            }
        }
    }
        return false;
    }

    //**********************************************************************************************
    //function to check empty fields unsubscribe form

    function isEmptyEmail(strfield1) {

    strfield1 = document.forms.newsletter_unsubscribe.email.value

      if (strfield1 == "" || strfield1 == null || !isNaN(strfield1) || strfield1.charAt(0) == ' ')
      {
      alert("Please insert a valid Email!")
      return false;
      }


      return true;
    }

    //function to check valid email address
    function isValidEmailCancel(){
      validRegExp = /^[^@]+@[^@]+.[a-z]{2,}$/i;
      strEmail = document.forms.newsletter_unsubscribe.email.value;

     // search email text for regular exp matches
      if (strEmail.search(validRegExp) == -1) 
     {
      alert('Email not valid! Please retry!');
      return false;
      } 
      return true; 
    }

    //function that performs all functions, defined in the onsubmit event handler

    function check_unsubscribe(){
    if (isEmptyEmail()){
            if (isValidEmailCancel()){
              return true;
        }
    }
        return false;
    }
```

When delete the new resource, that newsletter script is ok. But, when use the new jQuery resource get this failure.

Comment: Error says it all to me:    $( 'form.cmxform' ).find( 'li/label' )

Comment: Yeah but when i use the latest old jQuery.js (from 2006) the newsletter Script is ok...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to concatenate more than one selector in jQuery find you are using the wrong syntax

```
$( 'form.cmxform' ).find( 'li/label' ).not( '.nocmx' ).each( function( i ){
```

should become:

```
$( 'form.cmxform' ).find( 'li, label' ).not( '.nocmx' ).each( function( i ){
```

and this means you are looking for any li OR label tag in the DOM scope you have selected ('form.cmxform')